# Import ~500MB Turtle with Jena Fuseki yields error and crash

Tags: rdf, jena, turtle-rdf

I am trying to import a ~500MB .ttl RDF File, namely the [ESCO model](https://ec.europa.eu/esco/portal/downloadRequest/e00?resetLanguage=true&newLanguage=en) via the fuseki server of the [Apache Jena](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/io/) project. Running fuseki on Windows 10. Java memory is 1GB.

Progress bar is doing fine up until about half, then it gets stuck and after a while I get "Result: failed with message "org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException: Early EOF"" from the Jena frontend.

Is this a problem with the TTL file? Or something else like a Java config?

Comment: Hard to tell. You might try running the file through the Jena parser RIOT to check for any issues with it.

Comment: 1G of RAM isn't enough for the data size which is about 6 million triples (even if you are reading into a database, 1G of server space is quite small).  Give the server more heap space.